# Infinite loop CTE with OPTION (maxrecursion 0)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

I have CTE query with large record on it. Previously it worked fine. But lately, it throws an error for some members

> The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

So I put `OPTION (maxrecursion 0)` or `OPTION (maxrecursion 32767)` on my query, because I don't want to limit the records. But, the result is the query takes forever to load. How do I solve this?

Here's my code:

```
with cte as(
-- Anchor member definition
    SELECT  e.SponsorMemberID , e.MemberID, 1 AS Level
    FROM tblMember AS e 
    where e.memberid = @MemberID

union all

-- Recursive member definition
    select child.SponsorMemberID , child.MemberID, Level + 1
    from tblMember child 

join cte parent

on parent.MemberID = child.SponsorMemberID
)
-- Select the CTE result
    Select distinct a.* 
    from cte a
    option (maxrecursion 0)
```

**EDIT:** remove unnecessary code to easy understand

**SOLVED:** So the issue is not came from `maxrecursion`. It's from the CTE. I don't know why but possibly it contain any sponsor cycles: A -> B -> C -> A -> ... (Thanks to @HABO)

I tried this method and it works. [Infinite loop in CTE when parsing self-referencing table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13718168/infinite-loop-in-cte-when-parsing-self-referencing-table)

Comment: Are you sure the data doesn't contain any sponsor cycles: A -> B -> C -> A -> ...?  Or self-sponsored members?

Comment: have you checked the query plan? Have you tried to eliminate each of your joins to first check the cte, then check the HigRank, gt, TotCust separately?

Comment: HABO: no, the member on tblMember have an unique value

cha: I think the query is working fine. it works if the member has a small records

Comment: cha: I think the query is working fine. it works if the member has a small records

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are hitting the recursion limit, you either have considerable depth in sponsoring relationships or a loop in the data.  A query like the following will detect loops and terminate the recursion:

```
declare @tblMember as Table ( MemberId Int, SponsorMemberId Int );
insert into @tblMember ( MemberId, SponsorMemberId ) values
  ( 1, 2 ), ( 2, 3 ), ( 3, 5 ), ( 4, 5 ), ( 5, 1 ), ( 3, 3 );
declare @MemberId as Int = 3;
declare @False as Bit = 0, @True as Bit = 1;

with Children as (
  select MemberId, SponsorMemberId,
    Convert( VarChar(4096), '>' + Convert( VarChar(10), MemberId ) + '>' ) as Path, @False as Loop
    from @tblMember
    where MemberId = @MemberId
  union all
  select Child.MemberId, Child.SponsorMemberId,
    Convert( VarChar(4096), Path + Convert( VarChar(10), Child.MemberId ) + '>' ),
    case when CharIndex( '>' + Convert( VarChar(10), Child.MemberId ) + '>', Path ) = 0 then @False else @True end
    from @tblMember as Child inner join
      Children as Parent on Parent.MemberId = Child.SponsorMemberId
    where Parent.Loop = 0 )
  select *
    from Children
    option ( MaxRecursion 0 );
```

Comment: I run this query, is successful but result nothing. does it mean there's no looping on the CTE?

Comment: Hi HABO, I solve this issue. please check my update. thanks for the hint

Comment: @vantian - You didn't get any rows where `Loop` was `1`?  Did you change both occurrences of `@tblMember` to `tblMember` in the query?  Just curious since the answer you prefer uses a rather similar technique to track the path/levels to locate loops.

Comment: One more thing as you mentioned that there is no limit. so in case of CTE is having maxrecusrion is set to 0 is fine but the max limit of recursion in CTE is 32,767. Refer this http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-310.aspx