# Recursion in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, recursion, recursive-query

Hey guys I got a stored procedure that was recently modified by a co-worker who is on vacation, my experience in recursive SQL is quite limited. I am currently getting:

> The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion

Any ideas?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_BOM_GetRawMBOM]
   @JobNo varchar(20),
   @ImportNo int = NULL
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

IF @ImportNo IS NULL 
       SELECT @ImportNo = MAX(ImportNo) 
       FROM Import 
       WHERE JobNo = @JobNo AND SourceType = 'MBOM'

--Can't have aggregates in recursive portion of the common table,
--so get what we need to filter and inner join.
SELECT Drawing, MAX(ImportNo) AS ImportNo
INTO #DrawingImportNo 
FROM RawMBOM
WHERE 
    JobNo = @JobNo AND
    ImportNo <= @ImportNo AND
    Drawing NOT LIKE '_3_2_'
GROUP BY Drawing

SET NOCOUNT OFF

;WITH  Mbom AS (
    --Top (Skid) Level
    SELECT
        S.JobNo, 
        S.ImportNo, 
        CAST('»'+RTRIM(S.Drawing) AS varchar(500)) AS KeyField,
        S.Drawing AS Skid,
        S.Drawing,
        S.Drawing AS PartKey,  
        S.PartNo,
        S.Description,
        S.Qty,
        S.PartSize,
        S.PartLength,
        S.Material,
        S.CutLength,
        S.Ported,
        S.Rev,
        S.IsSub
    FROM    RawMbom S
        INNER JOIN #DrawingImportNo D ON D.Drawing = S.Drawing AND D.ImportNo = S.ImportNo 
    WHERE   
        JobNo = @JobNo AND
        RTRIM(PartKey) = '' AND
        NOT EXISTS (SELECT PartKey FROM RawMBOM WHERE JobNo = @JobNo AND ImportNo <= @ImportNo AND PartKey = S.Drawing)
    UNION ALL
    --Recursive parts and subassemblies
    SELECT
        R.JobNo, 
        R.ImportNo, 
        CAST(RTRIM(U.KeyField)+'»'+R.PartKey AS varchar(500)) AS KeyField,
        U.Skid,
        R.Drawing,
        R.PartKey,
        R.PartNo,
        R.Description,
        U.Qty * R.Qty AS Qty,
        R.PartSize,
        R.PartLength,
        R.Material,
        R.CutLength,
        R.Ported,
        R.Rev,
        R.IsSub
    FROM    RawMbom R
        INNER JOIN Mbom AS U ON R.Drawing = U.PartKey
        INNER JOIN #DrawingImportNo D ON D.Drawing = R.Drawing AND D.ImportNo = R.ImportNo
)
SELECT * FROM Mbom 
WHERE
    RTRIM(PartKey) <> '' AND IsSub = 0 AND --Remove assemblies from the mix
    UPPER(LEFT(PartNo,3)) <> 'REF'  AND --Don't pass because it is on ELT or EBOM
    (
        (DATALENGTH(RTRIM(PartSize))>0)  OR
        (DATALENGTH(RTRIM(PartLength))>0) OR
        (DATALENGTH(RTRIM(Material))>0)  OR
        (DATALENGTH(RTRIM(PartNo))>0)  
    ) -- Don't pass on blank parts.

DROP TABLE #DrawingImportNo
END
```

Comment: I attempted to increase the MAXRECURSION, but its definitely in an infinite loop of some sort.

Comment: Please share more details about your research and attempted solutions, and tell us why they didn't work.

Comment: Jeroen, increasing the maxrecursion rate did not work because it is stuck in an infinite loop, so no matter the limit (I attempted 0 [infinite] amongst others to no avail, they all were reached [except infinite, which I waited for a few minutes before killing])

Comment: I understand. But increasing the maxrecursion would probably be fighting symptoms instead of root cause analysis anyways. Surely you have done (or can do) more things to find a solution yourself first?

Comment: A quick trick for debugging a recursive query is to add a column `1 as Depth` to the initial query and `Mbom.Depth + 1` to the recursive part, then limit the recursion by adding `and Mbom.Depth < 3` to the `WHERE` clause. Often a quick look at the result will show what's going wrong.

Comment: fyi: A technique for detecting loops in data is shown in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080922/infinite-loop-cte-with-option-maxrecursion-0/15081353#15081353) answer.

Comment: @HABO, thank you! I was able to add this to the query and for the time being get it to run. This will help me debug more properly. I'm a bit of a novice in the realm of SQL recursion, so this was a big help. Upvoted your answer in the other thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via @HABO, I was able to add limitation to the depth of the query. This will allow me to run and debug it more properly.

For this, HABO has an answer over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080922/infinite-loop-cte-with-option-maxrecursion-0/15081353#15081353).

For those too lazy to click over, the detail is that you add a depth or level column to the primary function and increment it in the recursive section. 
New query, with highlights:

```
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON

IF @ImportNo IS NULL SELECT @ImportNo = MAX(ImportNo) FROM Import WHERE JobNo = @JobNo AND SourceType = 'MBOM'

--Can't have aggregates in recursive portion of the common table,
--so get what we need to filter and inner join.
SELECT Drawing, MAX(ImportNo) AS ImportNo
INTO #DrawingImportNo 
FROM RawMBOM
WHERE 
    JobNo = @JobNo AND
    ImportNo <= @ImportNo AND
    -- Work instruction P.25 x3x2x is a drawing for a prefabricated vessel.
    --Parts do not get processed in the BOM because parts come as
    --part of the vessel.  Example - Site Glasses
    Drawing NOT LIKE '_3_2_'
GROUP BY Drawing

SET NOCOUNT OFF

;WITH  Mbom AS (
    --Top (Skid) Level
    SELECT
        S.JobNo, 
        S.ImportNo, 
        CAST('»'+RTRIM(S.Drawing) AS varchar(500)) AS KeyField,
        S.Drawing AS Skid,
        S.Drawing,
        S.Drawing AS PartKey,  
        S.PartNo,
        S.Description,
        S.Qty,
        S.PartSize,
        S.PartLength,
        S.Material,
        S.CutLength,
        S.Ported,
        S.Rev,
        S.IsSub
        ,1 Depth
    FROM    RawMbom S
        INNER JOIN #DrawingImportNo D ON D.Drawing = S.Drawing AND D.ImportNo = S.ImportNo 
    WHERE   
        JobNo = @JobNo AND
        RTRIM(PartKey) = '' AND
        NOT EXISTS (SELECT PartKey FROM RawMBOM WHERE JobNo = @JobNo AND ImportNo <= @ImportNo AND PartKey = S.Drawing)
    UNION ALL
    --Recursive parts and subassemblies
    SELECT
        R.JobNo, 
        R.ImportNo, 
        CAST(RTRIM(U.KeyField)+'»'+R.PartKey AS varchar(500)) AS KeyField,
        U.Skid,
        R.Drawing,
        R.PartKey,
        R.PartNo,
        R.Description,
        U.Qty * R.Qty AS Qty,
        R.PartSize,
        R.PartLength,
        R.Material,
        R.CutLength,
        R.Ported,
        R.Rev,
        R.IsSub
        ,Depth + 1
    FROM    RawMbom R
        INNER JOIN Mbom AS U ON R.Drawing = U.PartKey
        INNER JOIN #DrawingImportNo D ON D.Drawing = R.Drawing AND D.ImportNo = R.ImportNo
    WHERE Depth < 10
)
SELECT * FROM Mbom 
WHERE
    RTRIM(PartKey) <> '' AND IsSub = 0 AND --Remove assemblies from the mix
    UPPER(LEFT(PartNo,3)) <> 'REF'  AND --Don't pass because it is on ELT or EBOM
    (
        (DATALENGTH(RTRIM(PartSize))>0)  OR
        (DATALENGTH(RTRIM(PartLength))>0) OR
        (DATALENGTH(RTRIM(Material))>0)  OR
        (DATALENGTH(RTRIM(PartNo))>0)  
    ) -- Don't pass on blank parts.

DROP TABLE #DrawingImportNo
END
```