# Recursive CTE across many-to-many tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, recursive-cte

I'm working a a recursive CTE to trace all relationships in a DB, using foreign keys, in order to create some test data. Everything is working well, up until the point that I hit a table that contains many-to-many relationships. I've taken a look at some of the other answers out there related to many-to-many tables, but it's just not clicking with me - can someone take a look at what I have and help point me in the right direction? Specifically what is happening is that I'm reaching a table that is a Budget/Client table (id, budgetid, clientid) from the Client side. At that point the recursion stops; I would want/expect it to traverse to the budget table (via budgetid) and continue to any related tables after that.

```
|Users      |      |Client       |       |BudgetClient |      |Budget       |
|userid (pk)|==\   |clientid (pk)|==\    |id (pk)      |   /==|budgetid (pk)|
                \==|userid (fk)  |   \   |budgetid (fk)|==/
                                      \==|clientid (fk)|
```

Existing code (current attempt) is below:

```
    WITH cte AS
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT fk.object_id, fk.schema_id, fk.parent_object_id, fc.parent_column_id, t.schema_id AS referenced_schema_id, fk.referenced_object_id, ic.column_id AS referenced_column_id, 1 AS [Level]
        FROM sys.foreign_keys fk
            INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON fk.referenced_object_id = t.object_id
            INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns fc ON fk.object_id = fc.constraint_object_id
            INNER JOIN sys.indexes i ON fk.referenced_object_id = i.object_id AND i.is_primary_key = 1
            INNER JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON i.object_id = ic.object_id AND i.index_id = ic.index_id
        WHERE fk.type = 'F' 
            AND fk.referenced_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Users', N'U')

        UNION ALL

        SELECT fk.object_id, fk.schema_id, fk.parent_object_id, fc.parent_column_id, t.schema_id, fk.referenced_object_id, ic.column_id AS referenced_column_id, cte.[Level] + 1
        FROM sys.foreign_keys fk     
            INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON fk.referenced_object_id = t.object_id
            INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns fc ON fk.object_id = fc.constraint_object_id
            INNER JOIN sys.indexes i ON fk.referenced_object_id = i.object_id AND i.is_primary_key = 1
            INNER JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON i.object_id = ic.object_id AND i.index_id = ic.index_id
            INNER JOIN cte ON fk.referenced_object_id = cte.parent_object_id
        WHERE fk.type = 'F' 
            AND fk.referenced_object_id <> cte.referenced_object_id
    ),
    cteHierarchy AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            OBJECT_NAME(cte.object_id) AS ReferringKey,
            SCHEMA_NAME(cte.schema_id) AS ReferringSchema,
            OBJECT_NAME(cte.parent_object_id) as ReferringTable,
            cte.parent_object_id AS reftableid,
            COL_NAME(cte.parent_object_id,cte.parent_column_id) ReferringColumn,
            SCHEMA_NAME(cte.referenced_schema_id) AS ReferencedSchema,
            OBJECT_NAME(cte.referenced_object_id) as ReferencedTable,
            COL_NAME(cte.referenced_object_id,cte.referenced_column_id) ReferencedColumn,
            [Level]
        FROM cte
    )
    SELECT ReferringKey, ReferringSchema, ReferringTable, ReferringColumn, ReferencedSchema, ReferencedTable, ReferencedColumn, [Level]
    FROM cteHierarchy
    ORDER BY [Level], ReferencedSchema, ReferencedTable, ReferringTable;
```

Sample data is below. DML is not necessary for this question, but provided to be thorough.

```
CREATE TABLE Users
(
    userid INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Users PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (userid)
);

CREATE TABLE Client
(
    clientid INT NOT NULL,
    userid INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Client PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (clientid),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Client_Users FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES Users (userid)
);

CREATE TABLE Budget
(
    budgetid INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Budget PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (budgetid)
);

CREATE TABLE BudgetClient
(
    id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    budgetid INT NOT NULL,
    clientid INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_BudgetClient PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_BudgetClient_Budget FOREIGN KEY (budgetid) REFERENCES Budget (budgetid),
    CONSTRAINT FK_BudgetClient_Client FOREIGN KEY (clientid) REFERENCES Client (clientid)
);

CREATE TABLE Company
(
    companyid INT NOT NULL,
    userid INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Company PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (companyid),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Company_Users FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES Users (userid)
);

CREATE TABLE CompanyType
(
    companytypeid INT NOT NULL,
    companyid INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_CompanyType PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (companytypeid),
    CONSTRAINT FK_CompanyType_Company FOREIGN KEY (companyid) REFERENCES Company (companyid)
);

CREATE TABLE CompanyTypeCategory
(
    companytypecategoryid INT NOT NULL,
    companytypeid INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_CompanyTypeCategory PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (companytypecategoryid),
    CONSTRAINT FK_CompanyTypeCategory_CompanyType FOREIGN KEY (companytypeid) REFERENCES CompanyType (companytypeid),
);

INSERT INTO Users (userid)
    VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10);

INSERT INTO Client (clientid,userid)
    VALUES (6,10),(7,3),(8,8),(9,5),(10,6);

INSERT INTO Budget (budgetid)
    VALUES (15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20),(21),(22),(23),(24),(25);

INSERT INTO BudgetClient (budgetid,clientid)
    VALUES (15,6),(16,7),(17,8),(19,9),(18,10),(21,6),(20,7),(25,8),(23,9),(24,10);

INSERT INTO Company (companyid,userid)
    VALUES (1,7),(5,1),(8,9),(12,2),(15,4);

INSERT INTO CompanyType (companytypeid, companyid)
    VALUES (1,1),(2,5),(3,8),(4,12),(5,15),(6,5),(7,8);

INSERT INTO CompanyTypeCategory (companytypecategoryid,companytypeid)
    VALUES (1,7),(2,1),(3,3),(4,2),(5,1),(6,1),(7,5),(8,4),(9,6),(10,7);
```

The white/green lines, with the exception of the 'Type' column, are currently returned. The green line is the many-to-many table, and the red line is what I want returned as well (the other 'one to many' on related to the green 'BudgetClient' table). Essentially the recursion is using foreign keys to trace the table relationships. So here, the top/anchor table is Users, which has two child tables - Client and Company, both one to many relationships. In turn, Client has one related table, BudgetClient, in a many to many relationship with Budget - BudgetClient ties Client & Budget together.

To be clear, my desired result is that ALL of the lines in the image below would be returned.

[image]

Comment: It's not clear to me from your question what you're trying to do.   Sample data and desired results would probably help.  Also, what is different from your desired results and the results your posted code gets?

Comment: I'll pull together some sample data now.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Aside: When you run into a table that references itself or a longer cycle of references between tables you may want to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080922/infinite-loop-cte-with-option-maxrecursion-0/15081353#15081353) answer for a way to detect loops and terminate the recursion.

Comment: @ZoharPeled DDL & DML have been added.

Comment: Why wouldn't you expect the red row to look more like the green row?   In a many-to-many relationship, the bridge table references two other tables, so why would you want the red row to have the bridge table be the referenced table instead of the referencing table like in the green row?

Comment: @TabAlleman What I'm trying to do is start at the anchor table, Users, and trace each relationship outwards using the foreign keys. So Users => Client => BudgetClient => Budget => (any tables that may lie beyond). Currently the red row doesn't appear at all - that is what I want to appear.

Comment: If you do a simple select from `sys.foreignkeys`, do you see any row at all that has `Budget` as a referring table and `BudgetClient` as the referenced table?   I bet you'll see the opposite instead.

Comment: @TabAlleman So it would appear at each level it would need to look back "up" as well as "down", and exclude the join that it had just traversed...

Comment: @Jake Yes, exactly.