# Table valued function for parent id

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, recursive-query

So I have a database table that looks like -

```
MemberId    LinkedMemberId
1           1
2           1
3           1
4           2
5           4
6           4
```

And I want to build a table value function where I can pass in 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 or 6 and it will return all of the values because they are linked.

Example -
I pass in 4, so I want 2, my `LinkedMemberId`. Now because I have 2, I also want the `LinkedMemberId` of 1. And now because I have 1, I also want the `MemberIds` associated with `LinkedMemberId` of 1.

Is there already an algorithm to get this kind of data?

Comment: search around for "hierarchical structure" on tsql

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for a hierarchical query that retrives all parents of a given node. A typical approach is a recursive common-table-expression:

```
with cte as (
    select LinkedMemberId, 1 lvl from mytable where memberId = ?
    union all
    select t.LinkedMemberId, c.lvl + 1
    from mytable t
    inner join cte c on c.LinkedMemberId = t.memberId
)
select * from cte
```

This gives you one row for each parent of the input `memberId` (which is represented by the `?` in the query). As a bonus, the second column contains an incrementing integer value that represents the level of the parent in the hierarchy (starting at 1 for the first level parent).

Comment: for the most part this works, but I don't have a termination check to get out of the recursive call.

Comment: @duckmike If the termination issue is caused by cycles in your data then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080922/infinite-loop-cte-with-option-maxrecursion-0/15081353#15081353) answer demonstrates a way to terminate the loops.